# JHipster: forbidden error when trying to access microservice from gateway

Tags: jhipster, microservices

I'm following these recommendations: https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/ to organize the architecture of my microservices applications.

I have a setting with some microservices to be accessed by a gateway. I've already put the same secret (jhipster.security.authentication.jwt.secret) for all components (gateway, microservices and registry).

But, when I try to consume a microservice from the gateway, by the following way, I always receive a Access Denied Message (Forbidden 403):

```
@FeignClient(value = "storageservice")
public interface StorageServiceClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "api/applications")
    ResponseEntity<List<ApplicationDTO>> getApplications();
}
```

I'm testing by this way (in my Gateway):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class StorageServiceTest {

@Inject
private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

@Inject
private RestTemplate template;

@Inject
private SecurityConfiguration security;

@Inject
private StorageServiceClient storageServiceClient;


@Inject
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@RequestMapping(value = "/apps",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<ApplicationDTO>> getApplications(){
    ResponseEntity<List<ApplicationDTO>> apps = storageServiceClient.getApplications();
    Stream.of(apps).forEach(System.out::println);
    return apps;
}
}
```

The interest thing is that I've tested the direct access to the microservice (via postman) and the routed access by the gateway and either have worked well. But, specifically in this case when I try to consume the microservice data from gateway via API, I receive the 403 error.

In my microservice I have the configuration (in MicroServiceConfiguration class ".antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()"). But in all the cases, when I'm testing via Postman, I'm always passing a valid JWT Token. But only in this specific case it doesn't works... I even tried to use a @Header annotation in my "StorageServiceClient" but it didn't any effect.

*********** EDITED ***********:

I've solved the authentication issue by creating a RequestInterceptor like that:

```
@Configuration
public class FeignConfig {

@Inject
private JHipsterProperties properties;

@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestTokenBearerInterceptor() {
    return requestTemplate -> {
        String token = Jwts.builder().
                setSubject("admin")
                .claim("auth", "admin")
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, properties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getJwt().getSecret())
                .compact();
        requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    };
}}
```

Comment: Consuming a service from the gateway code (not throught the gateway) is not common because it means you want to implement some business logic in the gateway, while it is supposed to be only a proxy. Could you clarifyyour goal and how you plan to use StorageServiceClient?

Comment: When the gateway is generated, it comes with a set of web application resources (including front-end). For this, I thought that the gateway project can be used also as an application, gathering many microservices resources to apply some business logic. I've seem some examples working like that. It isn't correct? Should I create another project to access the gateway?

Comment: The responsibilities of a JHipster gateway are security, isolating services from direct access with routing and load-balancing, serving the angular app to avoid CORS issues. So if your service is required for authentication, authorisations or routing, then it would make sense to implement it in the gateway

Comment: So, in this case, is not a gateway responsibility to gathering many services and applying business logic, right? But, about authentication and authorization issues, I shouldn't make clients to my microservices (in the way that I showed)? I have to set up some filter to configure the access control to each method? If I could not use Spring Security annotations in client methods, where can I configure this? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I don't uderstand

Comment: Indeed my previous statement was pretty confusing. :-) Trying to be simpler: as you said, if my service requires authentication, authorization or routing would make sense to implement it in the gateway. That's the case, but the right way to do that is by configuring routes permissions rather than consuming services from microservices, right? In this case, I'll only  consume services provided by the gateway (not from microservices directly). Thinking in this way, it really makes sense.

Comment: As usual it depends but one thing that could help you select one way or another is thinking where your service will store its data.